# Как добавить данные и проверять на условия в sqlite3 для тг бота?

Tags: sql, база-данных, telegram, бот

Мне нужно получить все значения и после этого проверить значение class_id  является ли это нужной строкой, если да тогда я смогу использовать её в дальнейшем, если нет буду выдавать ошибку. Вопрос: как мне это сделать?)

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
def db_table_val(username: str, user_name: str, user_surname: str, class_id: str):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (username, user_name, user_surname, class_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (user_name, user_surname, class_id))
    conn.commit()

def start(message):
    saved_message_group = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Привет <b>{0.first_name}</b>, напиши номер своей группы: (1, 2)'.format(message.from_user), parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(saved_message_group, save_group)
    us_name = message.from_user.first_name
    us_sname = message.from_user.last_name
    username = message.from_user.username

    db_table_val(class_id=?, user_name=us_name, user_surname=us_sname, username=username)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval = 0)
```

Вывод в консоль

```
File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\scheduleBot\main.py", line 12, in db_table_val
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO database (username, user_name, user_surname, class_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (user_name, user_surname, class_id)) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: database
```

Не видит мои таблицы..

Comment: Таблица действительно называется `database`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, исправил название таблицы

Comment: Ну? Теперь работает? Прежней ошибки нет?

Answer (score 0):

Проверку class_id можно сделать через if - else или try - except, не совсем понятно с чем сравнивать, если нужно сравнивать со значениями из таблицы базы данных, нужно предварительно сделать запрос с SELECT, а потом сравнивать.